# Experts - Form opens differently from design view vs from MS Access object list

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

Complicated form with subforms (source objects set during the forms load event) and then some 'autosizing' vba code.

Works well when this main form is in design view and switch to Form view.

However, if opened 'cold' (e.g. double click on the Access objects 'menu'), the vba code runs, but the resulting form doesn't react/respond to the code actions - e.g. doesn't resize, though the subform source objects are correctly set.

Not asking for detailed help on debugging this, but as an appeal to experts - are there conditions/circumstances/known gotchas you've run into where you've seen this type of behaviour - specifically vba code running but not having an effect when form is opened in form view directly (not from design view)?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You may try FormName.Refresh or FormName.Recalc or FormName.Requery in the main form or in the subforms.